# Reverse order when using _set.all

Tags: django, django-models

I have two relationships:

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    first_name  =models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Activity(models.Model):
    action      =models.CharField(max_length=200)
    whom        =models.ForeignKey("Contact", null=True, blank=True)
```

With

```
 contacts=Contact.objects.get(slug=contactslug)
```

I can call the specific Contant from my url request

And additionally

```
c = contacts.activity_set.all
```

lets me call all the activities.

How can I call the activities but in reverse order since `.order_by()` or `reverse()` doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 5):

This will probably work

```
reversed(contacts.activity_set.all())
```

But, you should do this:

```
class Activity(models.Model):
    action      =models.CharField(max_length=200)
    whom        =models.ForeignKey("Contact", null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['action']
```

or `['-action']`

Comment: Will `reversed()` force a queryset instance to internally evaluate (due to, like, all the unorthodox metaclass/overloading stuff in the `django.db.models.query.QuerySet` implementation)?

Comment: Well reversed triggers iteration so yes

Comment: I couldnt get it to work but if you use template tages in Django, if you use {% for a in activity reversed %}, it will reveal itself backwards.  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/builtins/#for